# conceptual doubt of the calculation of areas with integrals.What is the right thing to do?

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

I recently saw this problem

[image]

regarding the area under the curve they propose this solution
$$\int_{a}^{c}\left | f(x) \right |dx$$

however I believe this is the correct one

$$\int_{a}^{b}\left | f(x) \right |dx +\int_{b}^{c} f(x)dx$$

what is the correct solution and why?

Comment: What is difference between proposed and your belief?

Comment: @zkutch , hi ,in the first one I calculate ,evaluate and then take the absolute value , but as a part of the interval is negative the areas will be subtracted (knowing that the area is not negative !!!!)
In my case I add in both cases positive portions of area

Comment: In the interval from $c$ to $b$, your function is positive, meaning that $f(x) = |f(x)|$ and so the expression you've given is equal to the one given in the solution.

Comment: Both results in addition of positive value. No?

Comment: I have a little doubt about how to use the absolute value in the first one, please clarify the order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are equivalent:

$$\int_a^c\left|f(x)\right|\,dx=\int_a^b\left|f(x)\right|\,dx+\int_b^c\left|f(x)\right|\,dx=\int_a^b\left|f(x)\right|\,dx+\int_b^c f(x)\,dx,$$

since $f(x)\geq0$ for $x\in[b,c]$